# How do I include an object in a query-string as is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-string

I need a query-string to be in the format:

`brand=samsung&model={"type":"touch"}`

I am using the in built query-string module in Node.js

**How would I form my object in order to output the query-string above?**

My current object looks like this:

`{ brand: samsung, model: { type: 'touch' } }`

Which returns a query-string in the format:

`brand=samsung&model=`

I need to form the query-string without altering the URL.

Comment: are u using requestjs

Comment: @p0k8_ Im using request-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
const qs = require('querystring');

let object = {};

object.brand = "samsung"
object.model = JSON.stringify({
  "type": "touch"
});

console.log(qs.stringify(object));
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/YLOHT91892) is a  demo.

This is done with [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), the request will be interpreted as an object you described in your question.